# load background image from other page with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to load a background image from another ajax page and Im not really sure whats the best way?

In my index.html page I have the css background code and I want to load an image from another asp page.

My index.html file as it looks now:

```
<div id="bgimage" style="background-image: url(../images/theimage.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-attachment:fixed;">
```

and the imagepage.asp page that gets the right image from the db.

```
<div id="menuimage">
<img src="..user_images/<%=folderName%>/menuimage/<%=rs("big_image")%>" id="themenyimage"/>
</div>
```

Any suggestions appriciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
var temp_div = $('<div></div>');
temp_div.load('path.asp #menuimage', function() {
    $('#bgimage').css('background-image', temp_div.find('img').first().attr('src');
});
```

Can probably be optimised etc.

Comment: Thanks Blair, but it doesnt work, and I dont understand why Im afraid.

Comment: You might need to go through and debug it a bit. Make sure that you are getting results, make sure that the image is actually there, try putting the temp_div into the DOM to make sure that it loads, etc etc. Sorry I can't help further.